# One action for several CCNode

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating an action like this

```
id action = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:
                [CCSequence actions:
                    [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:TIMESPEED position:POINT_TOP],
                              [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:TIMESPEED position:POINT_START],
                              nil]];
```

I'd like to run this on several nodes

```
                for (Myitem* bonusitem in self.bonusitems) {
                    [bonusitem runAction:action];
                }
```

This crashes. If I do `[bonusitem runAction:[action copy]]` instead each time it works but I assume that I am responsible of releasing the action too. However, doing so also always crashes. So I just leave those unreleased and it works but AFAIK this would go against the copy rule now wouldn't it? (the copied actions would never be deallocated thus causing memory leaks)

Comment: I believe the copy is autoreleasing. Use ARC and stop worrying about this crap. ;)

Comment: I was brought up pre-ARC... Anyway I believe that use of copy is against the code...

Comment: many things cocos2d does isn't exactly cocoa-conformant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the code of any action subclass. You'll see that action's copy returns as autoreleased object. So you can use it's copies freely. You cannot use any action more than once.